# How to start up the standard editor from the command line in swift

Tags: swift, macos, command-line, foundation

I want to start up the standard editor from a swift command-line program. I tried the following code but the editor does not accept any input.

```swift
    let process = Process()
    let env = ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment
    guard let editor = env["EDITOR"] else { return }
    process.executableURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/usr/bin/env")
    process.arguments = [editor, someFile]
    try! process.run()
```

Which shows the editor. But when i press any key, I get the following error:

```
Vim: Error reading input, exiting...
Vim: Finished.
```